# hana xosdata json limitation

Tags: hana, xsodata

I would like to know if there are any JSON size limitation for response returned by HANA XSODATA service. I am working on a service which is returning huge volume of data (15-20K). When I call the service from browser I am receiving json parsing. I see that json is chopped off after certain character length.

Please let me know if any one has faced this issue and any resolution for this?

Comment: Hi, 
First, have you considered pagination to retrieve such a large result?
Then, can you clarify if are you using HANA 1 with XS Classic or HANA 2.0 with a JS module?

Comment: No, I haven't considered pagination. How do I enable pagination? I believe I am using XS classic. My calculation view is being  exposed as XSODATA service.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pagination (or paging) is not something you enable with just a config attribute or something as simple as that as far as I know.

It assumes first that your can handle it in your calculation view using the $skip & $count request parameters.

This will most likely require you to use XSJS instead of a straight forward XSOData service.

For example, you would need to extend your calculation view and:

- add a column with the Rank of the row
- add placeholder attributes to be used for the first row to be selected
- add placeholder attributes to be used for the row count

Once this is done, create a XSJS service where you can handle a $skip & $count request parameters.

Also, have you looked into the ***max_message_size_mb*** parameter in the [SAP HANA XS Configuration Parameters](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/1.0.12/en-US/86c9d3762a6b47039346f8ef075f8a7a.html?q=SAP%20HANA%20XS%20Configuration%20Parameters)